# Function to repeat a range of cells multiple times in a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to take a range of cells (SourceRange) and repeat it n times vertically in a column (Result Column). Here is an example of what I want to do:

[image]

Here is the [file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MCXH35jFWCAnjSS-ml_iwDthpCbOQnqJ3jA9pDY1M60/edit#gid=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=tocol(map(tocol(A2:A,1),lambda(Σ,wraprows(Σ,C2,Σ))),1,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly! If I had a second source range that I wanted to append to column E in the same way, how would I do that? In other words, say I had "green, purple, orange" as a second range that I wanted repeated 5 times after the 5 repeats of "blue, yellow, red". Can that be done?

Comment: Lets say "green, purple, orange" are in Column B then try this `=tocol(map(tocol(A2:B,1,1),lambda(Σ,wraprows(Σ,C2,Σ))),1,1)` OR  `={tocol(map(tocol(A2:A,1),lambda(Σ,wraprows(Σ,C2,Σ))),1,1);tocol(map(tocol(B2:B,1,1),lambda(Σ,wraprows(Σ,C2,Σ))),1,1)}`

Comment: @rockinfreackshow I used the 2nd option because the ranges aren't side by side. Worked perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: Another variation: If my source range is multiple columns, how can I get the output to show the additional columns? I've modified the Google Sheet to show this use case.

Comment: Try: `=query(reduce(wraprows(,3,),sequence(counta(A2:A)),lambda(a,c,{a;index(if(sequence(E2),index(A2:C,c)))})),"offset 1",0)`

Comment: Almost... It's grouping the results by the values in the first column (e.g. "blue, blue, blue, blue, blue, yellow, yellow, etc.". I'd like the sort order in the first column preserved (e.g. "blue, yellow, red, blue, yellow, red, etc.). Also, I'm wondering what the "3" is referring to -- is that the number of columns? And the "a" and "c"? I've updated the sheet with your most recent equation.

Comment: use: `=index(split(tocol(map(if(len(A2:A),A2:A&"|"&B2:B&"|"&C2:C,),lambda(Σ,wraprows(Σ,E2,Σ))),1,1),"|"))`

Comment: That worked! Really appreciate you working with me here. Each new solution seems to introduce another factor. What if I were to introduce an "x" in column D and I want to only pull in the rows with that "x" (in the updated sheet, that would be rows "blue" and "yellow"). So, I'd want to leave "red" out of the results altogether.